# How do I scale thousands of "long polling" thread in Rails with Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, email, heroku, concurrency

I'm working with IMAP and implemented the "IMAP IDLE" protocol. It's essentially an open connection that listens for new mail.

How I have it set up is that for each Email object, I can call something like email.listen_for_new_mail which does what it describes.

It opens up a connection on a new thread indefinitely and when the user receives new mail, it performs an action on that. It works great.

The problem is, when I have 100,000 emails I need to check, I'll essentially have 100,000 open threads listening for for each individual email.

Obviously, I can't just put this on one single dyno / worker. At the same time, I have to guarantee uniqueness of the thread. That is, I can't have two threads accidentally listening to "taco@gmail.com" or else it would duplicate certain actions and that would be bad.

What would be the best way to architect this? Other questions are:

- How can I reliably know when a thread has been killed? (Especially when the parent thread is terminated)
- How do I check for duplicate open threads?
- How should I handle my middle layer to communicate with the other threads that it has been open?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is this relevant?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673388/ruby-on-rails-with-imap-idle-for-multiple-accounts?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> How can I reliably know when a thread has been killed? (Especially
>   when the parent thread is terminated)

Ideally, design so that you don't need to know and it doesn't matter.

> How do I check for duplicate open threads?

Ideally, design so that you don't need to know and it doesn't matter.  You don't need to check for duplicate threads, just ensure there are no duplicate tasks.

How should I handle my middle layer to communicate with the other threads that it has been open?

Forget continually creating, terminating and destroying individual threads - think tasks, threadpools and queueing.

Comment: This is a good start. Any recommendations on how I can design these threads to be decoupled from having to know the existence of each other?